# Adding geo_shape data to elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, gson, kibana

I am new to Elasticsearch. I am trying to add **geo_shape** data to my Elasticsearch index using Java **elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client** version **6.4.0**

This is my index mapping

```
{
  "elktest": {
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "properties": {
          "Location": {
            "type": "geo_shape"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to add this data into the index

```
{
  "Location" : {
    "type": "polygon", 
   "coordinates" : [[ 
        [ -104.04405,45.01967 ],
        [ -111.03084,44.99904 ],
        [ -111.04131,41.011   ],
        [ -104.03375,41.00193 ],
        [ -104.04405,45.01967 ]
        ]]
  }
}
```

If I **POST** this data from Kibana Dev Tools console it works fine.

 From Java, I am trying to POST

```
String jsonString = "{\"Location\":\"{type: geo_polygon, coordinates:    [[             [ -105.04405,47.01967 ],        [ -111.03084,44.99904 ],        [ -111.04131,41.011   ],        [ -104.03375,41.00193 ],        [ -105.04405,47.01967 ]]] }\"}";

IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(indexName, indexType, 100);
request.source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);
IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I am getting this exception

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse [Location]]
Elasticsearch exception [type=parse_exception, reason=expected word but found: '{']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your stringified JSON is wrong. Has an extra `"` here:

```
                         here ------v
String jsonString = "{\"Location\":\"{type: ...
```

From browser's console

```
JSON.stringify({
  "Location" : {
    "type": "polygon", 
   "coordinates" : [[ 
        [ -104.04405,45.01967 ],
        [ -111.03084,44.99904 ],
        [ -111.04131,41.011   ],
        [ -104.03375,41.00193 ],
        [ -104.04405,45.01967 ]
        ]]
  }
})
# additional escaping needs to be done but ...
"{"Location":{"type":"polygon","coordinates":[[[-104.04405,45.01967],[-111.03084,44.99904],[-111.04131,41.011],[-104.03375,41.00193],[-104.04405,45.01967]]]}}"
```